# UnsafeInvokeInternal Error in JSON .NET in SSIS Script Task

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to use JSON.net in an SSIS project targeting SQL Server 2019 using the [assembly resolve functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dbrowne/how-to-load-an-assembly-in-a-ssis-script-task-that-isnt-in-the-gac), *as I cannot install the assembly in the GAC* because it's on a hosted server.

I have a small project in Visual Studio (it contains one script task) to prove I can use the assembly resolve. I created the original project in Visual Studio in the Citrix environment, which is on the server where I can't install the assembly to the GAC. When I run it in Visual Studio there, it actually works. I copied the project to my local machine and edited the script, only changing the reference to point to the assembly in a path on my local machine. It fails with the below, and it never opens the debugger or gets to the breakpoints I've set - even when the offending line is in a try-catch. The message appears in a generic message box, and never opens the script.

> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

I've identified the line that causes the issue. It's the line with "JsonConvert". If I comment it out, it opens in the debugger. Below is the entirety of my script task.

I'm trying to understand why it works on one machine, both running VS 2019, targeting SSIS on SQL Server 2019. There are small differences in versions of VS: one is 16.11.22 (local) and the Citrix version is 16.11.26.The version of SQL Server Data Tools is the same.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{
    public void Main()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);

        string myJson = "{\"folderName\" : \"TestFolder\"}";

        try
        {
            FolderData myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FolderData>(myJson);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
           
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Name.Contains("Newtonsoft"))
        {
            string path = @"c:\users\user123\Downloads\";
            return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "Newtonsoft.Json.dll"));
        }
        return null;
    }

    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
}

public class FolderData
{
    public string FolderName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Seems like the .dll using fot the JSONConvert from your server to your local may be different.  Script tasks never have good error messages when debugging.  Whenever doing script tasks in SSIS (for anything not standard) I create a console app on my machine and put the code in there and test/step through and it shows errors much better and actually gives readable errors.  It does add some more work to convert from console back to SSIS but not too much and makes life much easier.

Comment: It ran perfectly fine in LinqPad. I haven't tried a console app, though. It should be the same DLL - it came from the same zip file. (And I did unblock the zip file before extracting the file, thinking maybe it sees it as "unsafe".)

Comment: I've never had a Nuget work in SSIS. I am a convert to Console Apps now. Plus SSIS script tasks is still in Framework and not Core, plus no async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was not the JSON.net assembly. It turns out the solution was to set my project to NOT use the 64-bit runtime by right-clicking my project, selecting properties-->Configuration Properties-->Debugging, and setting Run64BitRuntime to False.

I have successfully verified it twice by changing it back and forth. Set to true, it fails. Set to false and it runs and will open the debugger.